# Python dictionary of lists, insertion and update with variable key

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to use a dictionary, with string as key type, and list of strings as value type.

```
myDict = {}

def addToDictionary(key_str, val_str):
    myDict[key_str].append(val_str)

>>KeyError
```

My question is, why does this not work? If key_str does not exist in dict, then it should create it and append val_str in the list of values. Seems very straightforward to me, not sure why python is complaining.

Comment: Why should it create it? You don't have anything telling it to do that.

Comment: Well, C++'s STL container does it. So it's pretty nature to assume that python does it too.

Comment: The reason C++ does this is because you have to specify the type of the dictionary value when you construct the dictionary. Notice that you never had to do this in Python: some of your values could be integers, others could be lists, so there is no reasonable choice for a default value.

Comment: I thought that the machine reserve memory and each time I try to add an item it would allocate more memory, so that it doesn't have to know the type before hand.

Comment: It doesn't need to. But exactly because of that, it can't create the list automatically, because it simply doesn't know it will need to create a list rather than anything rust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in dictionary class in Python does not have a default value. How could Python know what it should be anyway, since the values can be of any type? What you want is a `defaultdict` from the `collections` library.

```
from collections import defaultdict

# this establishes list as the default factory
myDict = defaultdict(list)

def addToDictionary(key_str, val_str):
    myDict[key_str].append(val_str)
```

Comment: Thanks mate. That solves it. I can't understand why python is so awkward sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the `setdefault` method:

```
myDict.setdefault(key_str, []).append(val_str)
```

The first time, key_str does not exists in the dictionary, so python will initialize it as a list with one element (val_str), the second time python will use the `append` method

Here the docs:

> setdefault(...)
>       D.setdefault(k[,d]) -> D.get(k,d), also set D[k]=d if k not in D

Answer (score 0):

You've almost answered your own question: if **key_str** does not exist in **myDict**, then myDict[key_str] is a keyError, not an empty list.  Although you can append to an empty list [ ], you *cannot* append to a non-existent list.

In short, the **dict** built-in doesn't read your mind in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary key hasn't been created yet.  You're trying to append and create a key at the same time which doesn't work.

I recommend Iafishers solution it seems best

```
def KeyGen(key_str, val_str):
    myDict[key_str] = val_str

def AddToDictionary(key_str, val_str):
    myDict[key_str].append(val_str)


KeyGen('testing', [1,2,3])

AddToDictionary('testing', 4)

print myDict
```

Comment: That is so awkward.